# Extends Console Interface for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I would like to add an object in the window.console global.

```
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

window.console.tron = Reactotron;
```

Although when I do that, TypeScript complains about the new object:

> error TS2339: Property 'tron' does not exist on type 'Console'.

I was thinking to extends the Console interface:

```
interface ConsoleWithTron extends Console {
  tron: any
};
```

Although, I'm not sure how to assign this new interface to my global console object?

Help would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Why is console capitalised?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because it refers to our _interface Console_ originally from `node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts`, but takes camelCase form when called as a property from our global `window` variable.

Comment: @Leo three years!  - thanks btw

Comment: @evolutionxbox Haha apologies for the necro! ❤️

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just augment the `Console` interface itself. See [merging interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
interface Console {
    tron: any
}
```

If you want to augment `Console` from inside a module, you have to wrap it inside `declare global { }` block. See [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

```
declare global {
    interface Console {
        tron: any
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error from `tsc` after doing so.... I've defined the interface before I add `tron` to the console object.

Comment: Are you adding this inside a module? You might have to wrap it inside a `declare global { }`. See [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

Answer (score 2):

Even better, we could add type safety with linting to our previous answer

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { Reactotron } from 'reactotron-core-client';
import { ReactotronReactNative } from 'reactotron-react-native';

declare global {
  interface Console {
    tron: Reactotron<ReactotronReactNative> & ReactotronReactNative;
  }
}
```

And assign it more simply

```
console.tron = Reactotron;
```